# regex lexer - name and number gets recognized on each other

Tags: c++, regex, lexer

So i have this basic vector of regexs and symbols:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> patterns = 
{
    {"\\+|\\\\|\\*|\\-|\\%|\\=", "OPERATOR"},
    {"[0-9]+", "NUMBER"},
    {"[a-zA-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*", "NAME"},
};
```

And this is how I find pattrens:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> matches;
for (auto pattern = patterns.begin(); pattern != patterns.end(); ++pattern)
    {
        std::regex regex(pattern->first);
        std::sregex_iterator words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(_input.begin(), _input.end(), regex);
        std::sregex_iterator words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

        for (std::sregex_iterator it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it)
        {
            matches[it->position()] = make_pair(it->str(), pattern->second);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
a45 NAME
45 NUMBER
= OPERATOR
77 NUMBER
```

And the problem is that a45 is a name but 45 is a part of the name but it is also a number but I don't want it to be recognized as number.
I don't know to overcome this kind of problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-overlapped matching, and for better performance, you should combine the regex's, then check which part matched.

```
"(\\+|\\\\|\\*|\\-|\\%|\\=)|([0-9]+)|([a-zA-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)"

 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           group 1          group 2         group 3
```

If capturing group 1 matched, then next "token" is an operator.
If capturing group 2 matched, then next "token" is a number.
If capturing group 3 matched, then next "token" is name.